# How to add 2 more file uploads to Script allowing filenames to be sent to database and files to directory

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Hey guys ive been trying to change this upload.php around and im quite new to this. I need to add two more file upload fields to the script so that i can upload 3 images at one time to the database where i can echo out the filenames in posts and save to files to a directory and i dont know how to change the code below to suit

```
     upload.php
     <?php
     $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
      if (!$link) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

      mysql_selectdb("tutorials_upload");
      if(!is_dir("uploads")){//do we need to make the uploads directory for the files?
     mkdir("uploads");//make the rest of the script safe, though this will only be done       once

    }

     function savedata(){
      global $_FILES, $_POST, $putItAt;
     $sql = "INSERT INTO `tutorials_upload`.`thefiles` (
     `ID` ,
     `Time` ,
     `FileLocation` ,
     `IP` ,
     `Title`
      )
      VALUES (
       NULL , UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) , '".mysql_real_escape_string($putItAt)."',      '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Title'])."'
      );";
      mysql_query($sql);

     }
        $putItAt = "uploads/".basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

      $putItAt = str_replace("php","txt", $putItAt);
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$putItAt)){

     savedata();
     header("location: listfiles.php");//redirect them to the listfiles.php page


     }else{
    if(copy($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$putItAt)){

      savedata();
       header("location: listfiles.php");
    }else{

       echo 'You totally failed. click <a href="index.php">here</a> to go back and try again.';
     }
     }
   ?>
```

the database is

```
      ID,
      Time,
      FileLocation,
      IP and Title
```

and i would like to add FileLocation2 and FileLocation3 to the database 
and the form is

```
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
        Choose your file to upload!
        <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
        <br />
         And what would you like to call it? <input name=“title” type=“text” />

         <input type="submit" value="upload file"/>
        </form>
```

What i need to do is add 2 more file upload fields to the form and post the file names to 2 more image name fields i will put in the database Thanks Guys

Comment: And maybe a few more text fields aswell if i can be done

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) would help.

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Send these files:<br />
      <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
    </form>
```

`$_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]`  would contain the first uploaded file.

`$_FILES['userfile']['name'][1]`  would contain the second . .  and so on.

You can use a `foreach` and perform the queries. Something like

```
foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $i => $name) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for that Mob but i dont know how to put your answers into the upload,php file im very new to php thanks again mate